# How much space is used by a package in rc state?

Tags: dpkg, disk-usage

If you uninstall a package, but don't purge it, `dpkg -l` will show it as `rc`, meaning removed, but config files are left. Is there an easy way to see how much space is still used by such a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config files should be listed in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.conffiles`. For example, with the `dpkg` package:

```
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/dpkg.conffiles 
/etc/alternatives/README
/etc/cron.daily/dpkg
/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
/etc/logrotate.d/dpkg
```

If there aren't too many files, you can use `xargs` and `du`:

```
$ xargs -a /var/lib/dpkg/info/dpkg.conffiles du -c
4       /etc/alternatives/README
4       /etc/cron.daily/dpkg
4       /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
4       /etc/logrotate.d/dpkg
16      total
```

If there are too many files, you'll see multiple `total` lines.

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually looking at `linux-image` packages, and an uninstalled one doesn't seem to have any config files left. Am I guessing right that the `<package>.list` file shows the files presently on the system belonging to that package? An installed kernel's `list` file has around a thousand files, while an uninstalled ones is empty? So an uninstalled, but not purged, kernel leaves then only these files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`?

Comment: @muk.li Yes, and as far as I know, the kernel packages don't have any fils in `/etc` (well, not the actual image packages anyway). And yes, the `conffiles` file would be removed when the package is removed, but the `list` will match closely with `conffiles` (with the difference being that any containing directories are listed separately).